# How to use ng-transclude in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives `free-form` and `free-form-canvas`

```
<div ng-repeat="controls in ctrls">
   <free-form></free-form>
</div>
```

free-form.html

```
<div id="{{controls.uiControlInstanceId}}">
  <free-form-canvas data-controls="controls"></free-form-canvas>
</div>
```

free-form-canvas.html

```
<div>
  <!-- ctrl -->
  <div ng-switch on="ctrl.controlProps[1].containerInstance.uiContainerTypeId">
    <div ng-switch-when="NAVIGATOR">
      <navigation></navigation>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="CAROUSEL_VIEW">
      <carousel></carousel>
    </div>
    <web-tile ng-switch-when="WEB_TILE" class="drag_tiles" tilegroup="tileGroups">
    </web-tile>
<!-- <news-bulletin data-bulletin="" ng-switch-when="WEB_BULLETIN_BOARD"></news-bulletin> -->
  </div>
  <floating-options></floating-options>
  <floating-popup></floating-popup>
</div>
```

but I need to make transclude free form canvas i.e,

```
<div ng-repeat="controls in ctrls">
  <div id="{{controls.uiControlInstanceId}}">
    <free-form-canvas data-controls="controls"></free-form-canvas>

    <!-- I need to include free form canvas here it self but nothing gets display -->

    <div>
      <!-- ctrl -->
      <div ng-switch on="ctrl.controlProps[1].containerInstance.uiContainerTypeId">
        <div ng-switch-when="NAVIGATOR">
          <navigation></navigation>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="CAROUSEL_VIEW">
          <carousel></carousel>
        </div>
        <web-tile ng-switch-when="WEB_TILE" class="drag_tiles" tilegroup="tileGroups">
        </web-tile>
<!-- <news-bulletin data-bulletin="" ng-switch-when="WEB_BULLETIN_BOARD"></news-bulletin> -->
      </div>
      <floating-options></floating-options>
      <floating-popup></floating-popup>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

by using `ng-transclude` I can solve this but I didn't know how to use `ng-transclude`.

Comment: You don't need a transclude - `<free-form>` has has the template with `<free-form-canvas>` and so it will be included as the content of `<free-form>`. The only difference is that in the output you will have `<free-form> <free-form-canvas>....</free-form>`, i.e. the output would have a wrapping `<free-form>`, which you don't have in your example, but that shouldn't matter. If you really care, you could use `replace: true` (although it is being deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

As noted above by `New Dev`:

> You don't need a transclude - `<free-form>` has the template with `<free-form-canvas>` and so it will be included as the content of `<free-form>`. The only difference is that in the output you will have `<free-form> <free-form-canvas>....</free-form>`, i.e. the output would have a wrapping `<free-form>`, which you don't have in your example, but that shouldn't matter. If you really care, you could use replace: true (although it is being deprecated).